# Remove the first number in every element in an array

Tags: python, arrays

how can i remove the first 0 from every element in an array.
Suppose the array contains `[0rf32,0sef2,0fhse]` i want it to display `[rf32,sef2,fhse]`
is there a method or function to do that?

Comment: What have you tried ? Is that an array of string ?

Comment: I think you do: `[x[1:] for x in your_array]`, read more about string slicing.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and how to provide a [mre] to avoid downvotes to your questions in the future. Note that your list is not valid Python syntax and that you are expected to show some efforts in solving your own problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Comment: @RoshinRaphel not related to the question. It is about **modifying** elements, not **removing** them...

Answer (score 3):

You can use slicing notation

```
values = ['0rf32', '0sef2', '0fhse']
values = [value[1:] for value in values]
```

To remove the first only if it is a **zero** do

```
values = [value.lstrip("0") for value in values]
```

Comment: This will produce undesired results if the value doesn't start with a zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice every item in the array.
In your code, for example, if you want to display `'rf32'` from `'0rf32'` it would be something like:

```py
str = '0rf32'
strResult = str[1:]
print(strResult)
```

I also think that it can be done with regular expressions (`re` module on Python). Here you have the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension and `lstrip()` to remove zeros from the start of each array value:

```
array = ['0rf32', '0sef2', '0fhse']
array = [item.lstrip('0') for item in array]
print(array)
```

Output:

```
['rf32', 'sef2', 'fhse']
```